# How to detect obfuscator (de4dot shows: Detected unknown obfuscator)

Tags: deobfuscation, de4dot

Generally, I use `de4dot` to detect obfuscator or deobfuscate. But some files are protected as they show:

```
Detected unknown obfuscator
```

What are ways to detect the obfuscator of .exe?

Comment: You're asking for ways to do it automatically (i.e., with a software), correct?

Comment: @user202729 doenst matter,if there is automatic, it will be better of course, like `de4dot`